# HTML5 App with fast clicking

Tags: javascript, html, click, touch, multi-touch

I'm developing an HTML5 game that involves fast clicking and I can't seem to make it work well.
I'm not using canvas and I'm using the Cocoon.js launcher to see my game for now.

I'm also using fastclick.js to remove the 300ms delay, but if the user touch two buttons really fast, the second touch doesn't work. What can I do to make this work in HTML5?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve this problem using javascript's "touchstart" event instead of the click function. Anyone with the same problem, just lookup "javascript touch events" and you're all set. No plugins needed too.